# Which IO classes are optimal for sending/receiving integer expressions through sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket, java-io

I've been learning about client/server programs in Java and I am overwhelmed with the many different ways of handling reading and writing to and from the server/client. My goal is to send 2-operand integer expressions one at a time from a client to a server which will evaluate them and return the result. I've listed the IO options that I've encountered below.

**Input Examples**

```
 - Scanner input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
 - DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
 - BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 - InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
       DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(in);
 - DataInputStream input =new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 - InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
```

**Output Examples**

```
 - PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
 - DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 - OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
       DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(out);
 - PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 - OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
 - ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Out of all of these approaches, which of them would be ideal for my simple needs? Also, please let me know if some of these are dated approaches or if there is a newer, conventional approach that is used for basic socket IO these days. Thank you.

Comment: I tend to use BufferedReader and BuffereWriter classes if the protocol is text-based, and I use text-based protocols whenever possible. I do this mainly for the ease of debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Know that other than doing it just to learn it, there's really not so many good reasons to use raw Sockets as you are talking about, rather than starting by building on the WebSocket protocols. Starting with WebSockets will save you a lot of headaches

To start with, you need to decide if you want/need a communication protocol (like http, which uses headers to provide meta information on the request and the response) You say sending two integers and receiving back a processed result. Do you ever envision sending some other kind of data back and forth? If so, you'll want a communication protocol (ex. http with has headers with meta information like content-type, etc) so that the receiver can understand what is being sent.

You may want to check out DataFetcher and ServerSocketEx here: (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/) DataFetcher is a threadable callback listener for messages on an InputStream. ServerSocketEx takes care of some of the plumbing in using ServerSockets.

As far as the classes you mentioned above: Readers/Writers are for reading and writing text - not binary. If you are going to do text-based communication, you should pick a text format (utf-8 would make a good default choice) and make sure the sender and receiver have agreement on that.

You only need stream buffers if you are doing *inefficient reading/writing* i.e. reading line by line rather than just gobbling bytes or wanting to write several messages before sending it all together over the socket.

And don't use Data or Object streams - these are legacy (Data streams can only communicate with Java backends) and no one really uses them.

One last word of advice: Be aware of java.io.SocketException (I think ServerSocketEx handles this). SocketExceptions are a healthy part of socket communication: It means the socket connection has been closed, and it also frees up any reader threads that may have been waiting for more information to come in. So if/when you get this, don't panic. Don't try to fix it. But instead handle it accordingly.

Comment: Too much waffling here about highly irrelevant application protocols, and the part about buffering is incorrect. It is when you are reading a byte at a time that you need buffering. Nothing inefficient about reading lines with `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and of course it *is* buffered by definition.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I agree that reading a byte at a time is inefficient. But here's the difference I was trying to draw: If you are loading a JPEG or an XML file, you need to load the WHOLE STREAM FIRST before you start to process, to make sure that it is valid. This is what I am calling *efficient reading*. When you are using BufferedReader.readLine(), there could well be more characters in the stream that you have not read yet while you are processing that line.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Not only that, but you need a buffer to be able to inspect the read data for new line characters, assuming that you are not reading 1 byte at a time, which we both agree is inefficient. The difference I am making is when you are reading the data as fast as possible (with no interruptions) vs. inspecting the data as it comes in